# How to send message from Python server to java client

Tags: java, python, sockets

I have made a python server that can receive String message from java client using socket,now i want to send string message from python server to java client please help me.I am new to java please help me.!
Here's java code:

```
public client(String address, int port) throws IOException {
    // establish a connection
    try {
        socket = new Socket(address, port);
        System.out.println("Connected");

        // takes input from terminal
        input = new DataInputStream(System.in);

        // sends output to the socket
        out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        System.out.print(input);

    } catch(UnknownHostException u) {
        System.out.println(u);
    }


    // string to read message from input
    String line = "";

    // keep reading until "Over" is input
    while (!line.equals("Over")) {
        try {
            line = br.readLine();
            out.writeUTF(line);
        } catch(IOException i) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }

    // close the connection
    try {
        input.close();
        out.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch(IOException i) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    client client = new client("127.0.0.1", 12345);
}
```

Here's python server code to send message to java client:

```
 c, addr = s.accept()
 c.sendall('Thank you for connecting'.encode())
```

## #

Comment: I see code, but no problem statement.

Comment: please tell me how to print the received message from python server in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the link:
https://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/java-socket-client-examples-tcp-ip
And code from there:

```
InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
byte[] data =…
input.read(data);
```

But check that link.